# Update / reload files silently

Tags: texniccenter

Any way to update / reload files silently in TeXnic Center? Since I often work in combinatio with other tools, it's kind of annoying, that it ask for reloading files on every extern change and scrolls to the bottom.

In Notepad++ both things can be disabled: the reload prompt and the scroll to bottom action.

To be more precise: When the content of a file opened in TXC is being altered by another program, TXC prompts for each altered file as soon as it gets activated again, whether the corresponding file should get reloaded. It also autoscrolls each file to it's <strike>end</strike> first line. Working on multiple `.tex` files with various tool along with TXC therefore becomes inconvenient.

[image]

Notepad++ allows for such behavior:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean?  The message that there are package(s) missing and have to be downloaded from MiKTeX?  Perhaps you can add a screenshot of this message to your question?

Comment: I bet you are using a more powerful editor to edit the files and use TXC solely for compiling? I bet you editor can take care of that :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Too long for a comment!

Okay, you have several `tex` files open in TeXnicCenter and you change some of them with an other program, right? Then the given message comes up.

As far as I know there is **no option** or **no other parameter** to force TeXnicCenter to reload automatically changed files. I think it would be a very dangerous behaviour (you **lose control** if you want changes or not!).

Create a project in TeXnicCenter, create a main `tex` file loading all needed other `tex` files (`\include`/`\input`) and compile in TeXnicCenter always the main file after you changed the other `tex` files with another program(s).  (Remark: Would be intresting why you want to do that ...) So you need not to have these `tex` files opend in TeXnicCenter. But you can, if you need it, open them easy by clicking on the file names in the navigator part (left side) of TeXnicCenter.

Or just ask the support of TeXnicCenter on the homepage to add such an option. But then you will have to argue why that could be helpful.

Comment: yeah, I'm aware of the problems, which can occur concerning control. While it's not a solution, since I actually *do* edit files in TXC and do not use it for compilation only, it's at least some kind of workaround for in some situations. The problem behind it is, that the search & replace functionality in TXC is rather poor. Replacing throughout a project is far easier accomplished with other tools (such as [TextCrawler](http://www.digitalvolcano.co.uk/textcrawler.html) for instance). There should be no problem in at least add this functionality to TXC, as these can be disabled by default.

Comment: Indeed, they are disabled by default in [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/).